# Using jQuery with kotlin and gradle (JS backend)

Tags: javascript, jquery, kotlin, gradle

I'm currently trying to get a simple example running in which jQuery can be used by kotlin code compiled to JS with the help of gradle. So far I pieced together the following elements which should be enough according to older descriptions using the `kotlin.js.externals:kotlin-js-jquery:3.2.0-0` package by adding it like this to the `build.gradle.kts` of the project:

```kotlin
repositories {
    ...
    mavenCentral()
    maven(url = uri("https://kotlin.bintray.com/js-externals"))
}

dependencies {
    implementation("kotlin.js.externals:kotlin-js-jquery:3.2.0-0")
}
```

After adding the package I can sucessfully import the corresponding kotlin package in a simple Kotlin file like this:

```kotlin
import js.externals.jquery.jQuery

fun main() {
    console.log(jQuery("div"))
}
```

But this sadly fails if executed with the following stack trace in the JS console:

```
Uncaught TypeError: $module$jquery is not a function
    at main (simple.kt?9d2a:4)
    at Object.eval (yet_another_one.js:14)
    at eval (yet_another_one.js:5)
    at eval (yet_another_one.js:8)
    at Object../kotlin-dce-dev/yet_another_one.js (yet_another_one.js:515)
    at __webpack_require__ (yet_another_one.js:30)
    at Object.0 (yet_another_one.js:527)
    at __webpack_require__ (yet_another_one.js:30)
    at yet_another_one.js:94
    at yet_another_one.js:97
```

After this I checked the packages webpack used for the bundling and I found out that as soon as the `kotlin.js.externals:kotlin-js-jquery:3.2.0-0` package is used the following jquery.js file gets used instead of the one with the actual code:

```js
(function (root, factory) {
  if (typeof define === 'function' && define.amd)
    define(['exports', 'kotlin'], factory);
  else if (typeof exports === 'object')
    factory(module.exports, require('kotlin'));
  else {
    if (typeof kotlin === 'undefined') {
      throw new Error("Error loading module 'jquery'. Its dependency 'kotlin' was not found. Please, check whether 'kotlin' is loaded prior to 'jquery'.");
    }
    root.jquery = factory(typeof jquery === 'undefined' ? {} : jquery, kotlin);
  }
}(this, function (_, Kotlin) {
  'use strict';
  Kotlin.defineModule('jquery', _);
  return _;
}));

//# sourceMappingURL=jquery.js.map
```

As this looks a bit strange to me as the jquery code seems not to be found anywhere I also tried adding it as a NPM dependency to the `build.gradle.kts` like this:

```kotlin
dependencies {
    ...
    implementation(npm("jquery", "3.6.0"))
}
```

But doing so didn't change a thing. Webpack still uses the jquery.js file shown above (and maybe rightfully so), but it also still doesn't work.

I would appreciate any help to get this working as I already invested a lot of time in it and I'm currently kinda hopeless :(.

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

To create a simple example, start a multiplatform project from the IntelliJ IDEA:
Select: File -> New Project
In the new window on the left hand select: Kotlin
In the main pane select the project template "Full-stack Web Application"
Use Build-System "Gradle Kotlin" to have best compatibility.

After this, Dukat is installed to generate your externals for jQuery:
Simply go to `build.kts` (your gradle build file) and under dependencies of `jsMain` add:

```
        val jsMain by getting {
            dependencies {
                /// ... ommitted pre-installed directives
                implementation(npm("@types/jquery","3.5.1", generateExternals = true))
                implementation(npm("jquery","3.5.1"))
            }
        }
```

After this you can simply access jquery using `jQuery` as a static import:
`import jQuery`

And use it like a kotlin library: `val xhr = jQuery.get("http://example.com")`

Comment: Before using jQuery in code, you might have to execute the gradle task `jsGenerateExternalsIntegrated` first.